# How to understand "that" in the sentence?

Tags: word-usage

The original text (except for the beginning and ending brackets):

> [...] One should have the courage to think uncomfortably, since it is
>   only by rejecting the convenient that one can come to think the truth.
>
> Not, after all, **that** there is any such thing as truth. At best we
>   can approach to some relative approximation. On the other hand, there
>   is surely such a thing as untruth. [...]

My qustion is on the boldfaced "**that**."

Please note there should be a tab space before "Not". That sentence is the beginning of a new paragraph.

Can "**that**" be dropped, making the sentence as:

> Not, after all, there is any such thing as truth.

Or is it a conjunction in an elided sentence, something like :

> [**I would argue**] **that** there is **not** any such thing as truth
>   **after all**. At best we can approach to some relative approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Not that" is an idiomatic phrase and needs to be used in its entirety. It's used to diminish the importance of or contradict the statement that comes before it.

Examples:

*He lost ten pounds, not that it matters because he still can't fit into his pants.*

*She's wearing a sweater, not that it's cold out.*

*He graduated from Harvard, not that is why he was hired.*